# formula to find the diameter of an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry

Find the minimum width and diameter. 
If I have an isosceles triangle with edges 7 cm, 7 cm, and 3 cm. What formula would I use to find the width of the triangle? I know that the minimum width is 3 cm but the diameter would cut across the triangle. How would I determine the length of the new edge?

Comment: How do you define the diameter?  Often it is the furthest distance between two points of the region.  If that is true, the diameter is one of the long sides.

Comment: @RossMillikan The diameter is defined as the least upper bound of the distances between any two points of the set. See my comment below as well.

Comment: What is your definition for the diameter of a triangle? It sounds like you are using width the way I would use base (not that width is incorrect). If you then mean diameter as equivalent to height, if you took the base as 7 and dropped a perpendicular to the opposite side (also 7), the length of that perpendicular is a minimum height. To get that length you could use the relationship that the product of two sides of a triangle is equal to the product of the altitude on the third side and the circumdiameter, so in this case $\frac{21}{2R} = h,$ where h is what you are calling the diameter.

Comment: @GregHill Yes, we are referring to the same thing. And that was my thinking as well but I had no idea how to go about solving fot the diameter we created as I have always had to use Pythagorean theorem or similar triangles. What is the formula that you mentioned? I do not understand your notation.

Comment: Your definition of diameter in the reply to me differs from the one in your reply to Greg Hill.  The LUB of distances between any two points of the triangle is a long side.  Your reply to Greg Hill is what is usually called the altitude.

Comment: @RossMillikan I see there are two definitions of diameter here and it would appear that your LUB one is correct. I'll delete my answer since unless the question is rephrased it's based on the wrong definition (nevertheless the altitude computation was a good exercise and I learned a more general definition of diameter than I knew ...)

Comment: @RossMillikan the diameter is not referring to the longest side, 7. I know this for a fact.

Comment: Then you need to find two points of the triangle further apart than 7, or change the definition of diameter from the LUB one you gave.  The LUB of the distances between two points of the triangle is 7.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to drop down a line from one of the vertices to the base giving you a right angle, then you can use basic trigonometry. I could be mistaken on what you mean by "width" and "diameter" of the triangle though, this depends on the orientation to me.

Comment: If we create a line from one vertex(we would use the vertex in between the two equal sides) to the opposite side, we cannot assume that the line we create will bisect the opposite side. Otherwise it would just be a matter of using Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: If you drop the line at a right angle it will bisect the odd side. Maybe we are not saying the same thing here. If you consider [this](http://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/lmcdowel/courses/ic210/F09/labs/IC210_Lab_3_IsoscelesTriangle.gif) image, we are dropping the line down from the upper vertex, this will create a right angle with the bottom line.

Answer (score 0):

Given the definition of diameter, the furthest two points are two vertices $7$ cm apart.